# Oval/Ellipse and chord based maths

Tags: math, trigonometry, ellipse

If I had a circle, I'd be happy, and there could be a song in there somewhere. I have an ellipse/Oval that looks like this:

[image: My Oval]

I know `R1`, r and a. I want to calculate `R2`. I'm assuming there is a scalar relationship between `R1` and `R2`. Every time I go near any angles I get completely lost. Every time I go near trying to calculate `r` based on `a` with radius `R1` because I think that might lead to the scalar thing, I get totally lost again. And if I try to calculate angles, again with the lost.

Can someone please help me find `R2` based on the rest. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Should be `a = 2 * R1 * sqrt(1-r^2/R2^2)`. Btw, showing an ellipsoid when your question is about ellipses is a bit misleading.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark - it is very much about programming, imagine some variables. It doesn't matter what language although I'm actually using OpenSCAD, but the question is about the math I need to render the ellipse.

Comment: @NicoSchertler: I thought 2D would be easier. I'm just trying to rewrite your formula :)